# Two buttons, only one work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, button, razor

I have two buttons and only one work...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Employer"))
 {

                <button name="Edit_hours">Edit</button>
 }
</td>
<td>

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Cancel", "Employer"))
 {

                <button name="Back">Back</button>
 }
```

Back button work properly, but the Edit button dasn't want work...
Controller and View should be good.

controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work ;/

Comment: MVC and Razor does not work like WebForms. There is no callback when you click a button. I'm not even sure why your "Back"-button work. It should not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to submit your form, then you need a `submit`. You should have something like

```
<input type="submit" value="Edit" id="editSubmit" />
```

`button` doesn't really have any implicit behaviour, so I don't know what you mean by 'it doesn't work'.

Comment: It works, but if I would like instead button put image?
In button it was easy, just put img....

Comment: You can use css background-image to style a submit.

Answer (score 1):

You have to transform your buttons to submit the form:

```
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Cancel" />
```

This way, your form will be posted. However, as @Christian Wattengård says in the comments, this is not WebForms.